# What is the expected MINIMUM value drawn from a uniform distribution between 0 and 1 after n trials?

Tags: uniform-distribution, order-statistics, extreme-value

Assume you draw a uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 1 *n* times.  How would one go about calculating the expected *minimum* number drawn after n trials?

In addition, how would one go about calculating a confidence interval to state that the minimum number drawn is in the interval [a,b] with m% confidence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic). The wiki indicates that the distribution of the minimum draw from a uniform distribution between 0 and 1 after $n$ trials is a beta distribution (I have not checked it for correctness which you should probably do.). Specifically, let $U_{(1)}$ be the minimum order statistic. Then:

$$U_{(1)} \sim B(1,n)$$

Therefore, the mean is $\frac{1}{1+n}$. You can use the beta distribution to identify $a$ and $b$ such that

$$\Pr(a \le U_{(1)} \le b) = 0.95.$$

By the way, the use of the term confidence interval is not appropriate in this context as you are not performing inference.

**Update**

Calculating $a$ and $b$ such that $\Pr(a \le U_{(1)} \le b) = 0.95$ is not straightforward. There are several possible ways in which you can calculate $a$ and $b$. One approach is to center the interval around the mean. In this approach, you would set:

$$a = \mu - \delta$$ and

$$b = \mu + \delta$$

where

$\mu = \frac{1}{1+n}$.

You would then calculate $\delta$ such that the required probability is 0.95. Do note that under this approach you may not be able to identify a symmetric interval around the mean for high $n$ but this is just my hunch.

Answer (score 5):

As Srikant suggests, you need to look at [order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

To add to Srikant's answer, you can simulate this process easily in R:

```
n = 10
N = 1000;sims = numeric(N)
for(i in 1:N)
  sims[i] = min(runif(n))

hist(sims, freq=FALSE)
x = seq(0,1,0.01)
lines(x, dbeta(x, 1, n), col=2)
```

to get:

[image]

---

**Slight digression**

This question is related to one of my favourite statistics problems, the [German tank problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem). This problem is about the maximum of uniform distributions, and can be summarised as:

> Suppose one is an Allied intelligence
> analyst during World War II, and one
> has some serial numbers of captured
> German tanks. Further, assume that the
> tanks are numbered sequentially from 1
> to N. How does one estimate the total
> number of tanks?
>
> Taken from wikipedia

Check out the wikipedia page for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Srikant, one can compute the CDF of the beta distribution, and find conditions on $a, b$ such that the interval $[a,b]$ contains the minimum of $n$ draws of a uniform with 95% probability. The condition is: $(1-a)^n - (1-b)^n = 0.95$. One attractive choice would then be the interval $[0,1 - 0.05^{1/n}]$. This is also the smallest interval with the desired property.